# Varying list item size using delegate in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have a list view. That list view has items. For each item I use setItemDelegate and I override the paint method of the delegate. The think is that in each item I am writing some text, and when the text is really long there is no space enough.

How can I resize the item from the paint event? since I get the bounding box of the drawn text in the paint event.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. When the item delegate's `paint` method is called, the list view has already been laid out and the `QPainter` you receive as argument might have a drawing surface that is the same size as the size hint or at least have a transform and clipping rect set to respect the size hint.

You must calculate the text size in the `QAbstractItemDelegate::sizeHint` method (using `QFontMetrics`) and return an appropriate size hint. [Cache your results](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qcache.html) for better performance.

Comment: Hi andref, thanks for your answer. As you say, I have tried this before your post and I realized that I have to do it with options.fontMetrics, using boundingText, etc etc... but the performance is not good, the list view items are loaded very slowly (only in the beginning).

Comment: You might want to try pre-calculating the size hints in a background thread before showing the items. Meanwhile, show a throbber in the GUI thread.

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement  `sizeHint` method

```
QListItemDelegat::QListItemDelegat(): QStyledItemDelegate(0){}
QSize

QListItemDelegat::sizeHint( const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const DataClass& data ) const
{
   const QStyle* style( QApplication::style( ) );
   QFont nameFont( option.font );

   nameFont.setWeight( QFont::Bold );
   const QFontMetrics nameFM( nameFont );
   const QString nameStr( data.GetName() );
   int nameWidth = nameFM.width(nameStr);
   int nameHeight = nameFM.height(nameStr);
   return QSize(nameWidth ,nameHeight)
}
```